# Spring - get ResultsSet from query

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I would like to use `Spring` `JDBCTemplate` but I would like to receive a `ResultSet`, which is not storing full query result in memory, as you would find executing standard statement with java `JDBC`. The closest I found to the `ResultSet` was

```
SqlRowSet sqlRowSet = template.getJdbcOperations().queryForRowSet(query, queryParameters);
```

but this loads the whole DB result into memory?

Comment: JDBCTemplate will close the connection before returning the results so doing a 'traditional' resultset approach with JDBCTemplate is not possible to my knowledge. Why exactly do you need a resultset? Maybe it can be solved in a different way?

Comment: the `SimpleJdbcOperations` class has a `queryForList` method which you might be able to use, but it won't give you a `ResultSet`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get a ResultSet object with JDBCTemplate you can retrieve the javax.sql.Connection with the following code:

```
Connection conn = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
```

And you can now perform a createStatement() or preparedStatement() to get the ResultSet object.
That's the only way it comes to my mind. I hope this will help you.

Comment: seems like the easiest way... I am wondering why the jdbc template did not decide to return a `ResultSet`

Answer (score 3):

Is it what you are looking for?

```
    JdbcTemplate t = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    t.query("select * from t1", new ResultSetExtractor<Object>() {
        public Object extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
            ... process your rs
            return null;
        }
    });
```