# Trouble reading a bytea (blob...) from database in java (1.5)

Tags: java, postgresql, blob

First off, I should mention I'm an absolute beginner in Java. I touched it a tiny little bit in school, 12 years ago. Haven't touched it since. Sorry if the question might sound a little bit basic.

We need to modify our client's web service which runs on Java 1.5. Yes, this is a very old version of java, and yes, until further notice, we are stuck with it. It's not our decision...

I need to read data from a Postgre table. The table has an auto increment ID, a vehicule ID, a data type ID, a timestamp and a data_value field containing a bytea, which represents the value. Each data type has a different data structure.

For example, data type 1 would be the oil temperature, and have only one value: the temperature. The data is represented on 2 bytes, and it is the temperature*10 in fahrenheit.

Data type 2 could be the GPS coordinates, and would be represented on 20 bytes. It has multiple values, where bytes 1-4 would represent the latitude, bytes 5-8 would be the longitude, 9-10 the altitude, 11 would be the number of satellites  etc.

The web service uses a org.springframework.jdbc.support.rowset.SqlRowSet to read the data from the other tables. The problem is that, in 1.5 at least, the SqlRowSet class has no way of reading a byte array/blob. I can read ints, doubles, strings, booleans, objects, and even bytes, but no byte array.

is there a way to convert the SqlRowSet into another type of recordset/rowset that would let me read byte arrays? Or is there another method of doing this that I'm not aware of?

I could try showing some of the code we have, but I don'T know what you guys would need to see, let me know if you need further info!

Thank you,

Comment: If you want to switch from Spring to plain JDBC, have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564378/spring-get-resultsset-from-query

Comment: I love this link. Basu's answer looks like it may solve my issue in the end, but I'll also look into converting this to a standard ResultSet or RowSet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not use something like below?

```
Blob obj = (Blob) rowSet.getObject("columnLabel");
```

Comment: Blob has been introduced in Java 1.7, so I cannot cast into a blob. However, based on your suggestion I MIGHT be able to do this:
byte[] obj = (byte[]) rowSet.getObject("columnLabel");

The compiler isn't complaining about that... I don't know if it'll work, I'll try to test the web service as soon as I get the accesses to the client's server. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure about this? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html

Comment: mhhh you are right. I was getting a class not found error, and when I looked onto the documentation it saif Java SE 7 in the title. But when I looked ito it more I could see it's available since 1.2! I have imported the interface, and it looks like it would work now!

Thank you guys I will try this I think it's going to work! I'll upvote Basu's answer right away and I'll mark it as the accepted answer as soon as I can test this!